# connecting to amazon elastic cache using .net memcached client

Tags: c#-4.0, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, memcached

I am trying to connect to Amazon's Elastic Cache using .NET with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.ElastiCacheCluster;
using Enyim.Caching;
using Enyim.Caching.Configuration;
using Enyim.Caching.Memcached;

namespace AmazonElasticCache
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ElastiCacheClusterConfig config = new ElastiCacheClusterConfig();
            MemcachedClient memClient = new MemcachedClient(config);


            // add data to the cluster
            if (memClient.Store(StoreMode.Set, "key", "some data"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully added data to cache.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed adding data to cache.");
            }


            var dataInStore = memClient.Get<string>("key");
            if (dataInStore == "some data")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully read data from store.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed reading data from cache.");
            }


            if (memClient.Remove("key"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully removed data from store.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed removing data from cache. ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Now adding a complex object");
            // add data to the cluster
            if (memClient.Store(StoreMode.Set, "key", new Itinerary()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully added data to cache.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed adding data to cache.");
            }

            var itinerary = memClient.Get<Itinerary>("key");
            if (itinerary != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully read data from store.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed reading data from cachee.");
            }


            if (memClient.Remove("key"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully removed data from store.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed removing data from cache. ");
            }

        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Itinerary
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string[] SomeOtherStuff { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With the following in app.config.

```
 <configSections>
        <section name="clusterclient" type="Amazon.ElastiCacheCluster.ClusterConfigSettings, Amazon.ElastiCacheCluster" />
    </configSections>

    <clusterclient>
        <!-- the hostname and port values are from step 1 above -->
        <endpoint hostname="my-cache-name.cfg.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com" port="11211" />
    </clusterclient>
```

Console application does not crash, none of the actions work.  I am running through all the failure paths.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

From the above code, I think you are trying to connect to AWS Elastic Service from localhost. To do this you need to follow some steps. Refer this answer for more information. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630124/access-elasticache-memcache-instance-from-local-development-environment)